# How call c# button event from JQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

This was my precedent implementation:

In **example.aspx**:

```
<asp:Button ID="rejectButton" runat="server" Text="REJECT" OnClick="OnRejectButtonClick"/>
```

and in **example.aspx.cs**:

```
protected void OnRejectButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // a lot of stuff...
    rejecter();
}
```

... this works.

Now I need a dialog for confirm the rejecting. Now my code is:

In **example.aspx**:

```
<asp:Button ID="rejectButton" runat="server" Text="REJECT" OnClientClick="return openDialog();"/>

<div id="dialog" title="Seleziona causa">
    <p>... bla bla...</p>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, show: "blind", hide: "blind",
            buttons: {
                "Okay": function () {
                    OnRejectButtonClick; // DOESN'T WORK!
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                },
                "Annulla": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function openDialog() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and **example.aspx.cs** is not changed.

But after this changing, the call to OnRejectButtonClick event doesn't fire anymore. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use jquery you can use this :

```
__doPostBack('<%= rejectButton.UniqueID %>', "");
```

so your code will be like this :

```
   $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, show: "blind", hide: "blind",
            buttons: {
                "Okay": function () {
                    __doPostBack('<%= rejectButton.UniqueID %>', "");
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                },
                "Annulla": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call it with jquery.

```
//before you click the button you should set a global variable
serverEx = true;
$("#rejectButton").click();
```

And in your `OnClientSciprt` method for the reject button `openDialog`

```
function openDialog() {

    if(serverEx)
       return true;

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
}
```

Add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the button like Chris Davis said.

Comment: Note that you will need `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the tag for this to work, as it's an ASP tag and the ID will be generated before transforming into HTML, resulting in a slightly different ID.

Comment: @ChrisDavis yes I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
__doPostBack('rejectButton','OnClick');
```

to actually perform the asp.net action.